# Preview HTML in Safari Web Inspector

Tags: safari, safari-extension, web-inspector, safari-web-inspector

When I open Web Inspector / Network / Any Request / Preview, I want to see rendered HTML, as Google Chrome does. But Safari shows only raw HTML. Is there any option to makes it render? Thank you!

Safari:

[image: Safari Preview]

Google Chrome:

[image: Google Chrome Preview]